# is_single and postid

Tags: wordpress

i am building a plugin for wordpress. At first, i was accounting with the default settings, where the URL of a post would be `http://localhost/worpress/?p=123`, and I was asking for is_single() in the `wp_footer` action.

When my plugin was ready, i went to try to cleanup my code. There are (at least) two things that i'm getting wrong:

1. Why does it return false, when i ask for `is_single()` in the `init` action or something sooner than `wp_footer`?
2. Why, when i try a var_dump($_REQUEST) (or _POST, or _GET) anywhere in my page cycle, i get an empty array, after switching the permalink options to url_friendly type?

Can anyone shed a light on this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

- `is_single()` will only return `true` if you are on a single post
- the `init` action hook occurs really early in the cycle; if you call `is_single` before the WP_Query is instantiated you'll get false.

To figure out whether you're calling `is_single` too early set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php`.  This is on line 81 of my version of wp-config.  You will see an error message from WordPress if you're calling it too early. (Plus it's a good tool to use during development.)

**Question 2:**

You're not getting `$_REQUEST` parameters after switching to friendly URL's because friendly URLs don't have a querystring (the name/value pairs that occur after the question mark in something like `http://localhost/worpress/?p=123`.)  Note that `http://localhost/worpress/foo/bar` doesn't have a question mark.

Comment: once again, thank you very much. I should start paying for your services :)
I understand the querystring vs pathname differences, but i found it really strange that the $_REQUEST object is completely empty.

Comment: No worries.  Wordpress takes the friendly URL and parses it into a WP_Query, which is kind of analogous to what you are looking for in $_REQUEST.  If you want to see how WP is interpreting the friendly URL try looking at `get_queried_object()`.  Cheers, Chris